# Saving Mediapipe Face Mesh Landmarks frame by frame from a video

Tags: python, opencv, points, face, mediapipe

> I want to know how to save the output of facial landmarks frame by frame from a video using Mediapipe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to iterate over `multi_face_landmarks` and append them to list and then you can do something like this:

```
columns = []
for i in range(1, 469):
    columns.append('x_'+str(i))
    columns.append('y_'+str(i))

data = pd.DataFrame(training_data, columns=columns)
data['label'] = 'somelabel'
data.to_csv('Data/filename.csv', index=False)
```